# Ruby class declaration syntax

Tags: ruby

I have read these two lines of code in a file:this is the head of a class declaration

```
class Myclass::Event

  class DeprecatedMethod < StandardError; end
```

I understand that the first line declares a class named `Event` in the name space `LogStash`. I would like to know what the second line means.

UPDATE:
Actually i learnt that a class in ruby should be declare like

```
class Myclass::Event


 // body of the classe here : methods and so on...

end
```

But what does it means to have something like this ?

```
class Myclass::Event
   class DeprecatedMethod < StandardError; end // whatdoes this line means ?  

  // body of the classe here : methods and so on...
   end
```

Comment: Specify yours Question. What exactly you wanna explain ?

Comment: @LukasBaliak sorry if i was not clear. i just updated my question.

Comment: Ok, so your answer is @SergioTulentsev.

Answer (score 3):

The second line declares `DeprecatedMethod` in a `LogStash::Event`. So, the fully qualified name (FQN) for that class is `LogStash::Event::DeprecatedMethod`. Also, this class is a subclass of `StandardError`.

> I understand that the first line declares a class named Event

Almost. The first line **opens** a class declaration. It is incomplete without a matching `end` and will produce syntax error if these two lines is all the code in the file. The second line is a complete declaration, though (has the matching `end`).

Comment: and `DeprecatedMethod` is a subclass from class `StandardError`

Comment: @LukasBaliak: yeah, but this is probably irrelevant here.

Comment: Maybe he don't understand whats `DeprecatedMethod < StandardError` exactly means :)

Comment: @LukasBaliak: yeah, maybe :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry if i was not clear. i just updated my question.

Comment: @GuyTalom: well, it's just a class definition inside of another class definition. Nothing unusual.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ok, but what is the interest to have a class definition with what seems to be just an  empty body ?

Comment: @GuyTalom: it's an error class. They often don't need any body.